# Setting up Virtual hosts through apache ,I keep getting "No input file specified"

Tags: php, apache, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to set up a virtual host so that I can access my laravel website when the url .I have set up everything but I get the following messsage instead of my website "No input file specified."

This is the code in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_socialmedia\laravel\public" 
ServerName hui.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the code in my hosts class :

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

192.168.10.10  homestead.app
192.168.10.10  blog.app
192.168.10.10  hui.com
```

Everything seems fine to me ,I have tried following many tutorials but I still get the same result .Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this in your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\laravel Task\laravel\blog" //here set your project storage path
ServerName    localhost.test.com            // set your url for your project 
<Directory "D:\laravel Task\laravel\blog">  // again set your project storage path
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted 
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

use this in your 'hosts' file

```
127.0.0.1      localhost.test.com
```

This is my hosts and vhosts codes and this working for me. if still you get any error then please check your Hosts and Vhosts file setup. you can post your error also

Answer (score 0):

These are the simplest templates I am using, both on windows and unix-like systems the slashes are forward (/)

That's the only difference I can spot between your config and mine

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@foo.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/foo/public"
    ServerName foo.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/foo-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/foo-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@baz.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/baz/public"
    ServerName baz.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/baz-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/baz-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@aux.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/aux/public"
    ServerName aux.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/aux-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/aux-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried changing the slashes but that didn't work too .And my path is definitely correct ,is there anything else that could be wrong ??

Comment: Does your xampp console shows any syntax errors? Is Skype running on your PC? (port conflict)

Comment: No I don't have skype running ,I m trying to find the errors now on the console but nothing really stands out that could be wrong

Comment: Are you sure that "No input file specified” message shows because of your Apache config files? Maybe your files are set correctly, and the fault is somewhere else. Please, type `echo "OK"; die();` in index.php in laravel's public directory

Comment: Maybe the issue could be with something else ,I just logically thought that there must be something wrong with the apache files ,yes I have typed that code into index.php now .

Comment: If you see the "OK" echo message then it's not apache's config fault